# How to automate transforming a table into a matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I've been looking for a way to automate transforming data in an Excel table into a matrix.
For example, from the left table into the matrix on the right, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Apparently PivotTable won't solve this problem because it can only aggregate. What I need is to show the individual data.

Is there a built-in function in Excel that solves this particular need or do I have to use VBA and if so, how?

Comment: have you tried putting all of this information in the 'row labels' section of the pivot table fields and messing around with formatting? The values area will only aggregate, but the row labels become subsets.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single built-in Excel function to achieve what you require. Either string together some sorting, moving and simple built-in functions if a once-off requirement - which I take it you would be quite capable of achieving without help - or use VBA.

The inference is either that you have a lot of entries (though that would make little difference to a once-off requirement) or that you require to do this often. As for many Excel questions here, quantity and frequency are relevant to selection of the appropriate approach and you (and others) may not get as good advice as otherwise if you leave those willing to answer to guess such details.

The complexity here seems mainly that you have a many-to-one relationship (in effect, the `I`). As for the "how?" of your question I would suggest (a) turn on macro recorder and complete the process as though once-off (b) sort by Level within Department (c) then offset and reposition Departments to suit and finally (d) align to suit.

If you have *specific* problems with your code, our sister site Stack Overflow has the magic necessary to fix them.

*Afterthought:* And a PivotTable may well be suitable as part of the process. Put all three fields as Row Labels (top down: Department, Level, Name), Move `Low` down, Copy/Paste Special/Values and all that is left is a little repositioning.

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestion. The solution will be used frequently as part of processes to analyze the data and also as a kind of report. Due to the frequency, I'm looking for a way to automate the task. The entries vary from time to time. I noticed that I could use PivotTable to get them grouped together as Row Labels as you've mentioned. Probably it's a good start before I use manual or VBA to reposition the Department as columns. Or I might try to get 2 dimensional array of 1 dimension dynamic array, populate them then later on assign them to the cells using VBA.